# Powershell Net.WebRequest Timeout don't works

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

```
$url  = "ftp://google.com/"

$WR = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$WR.Credentials = [Net.NetworkCredential]::new("anonymous","")
$WR.Timeout=3500
$WR.Method = [Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::ListDirectory
$WR.GetResponse()
```

With proper url this code works correctly. But if i set wrong URL, powershell hangs for a several minutes, although i set timeout 3.5 seconds.
Why it happening? I set timeout parameter purposely for case like this (wrong url).

To Doug Maurer:

Good url:

```
$url  = "ftp://ftp.intel.com/images/"

$WR = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$WR.Credentials = [Net.NetworkCredential]::new("anonymous","")
$WR.Timeout=3500
$WR.Method = [Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::ListDirectory
$WR.GetResponse()
# The response is received
```

Ur code test:

```
$url  = "ftp://ftp.intel.com/images/"

try{
    $null = Test-Connection $url -Count 1 -ErrorAction stop
    write-host good, continue your code here -ForegroundColor Green
    $WR = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
    $WR.Credentials = [Net.NetworkCredential]::new("anonymous","")
    $WR.Timeout=3500
    $WR.Method = [Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::ListDirectory
    $WR.GetResponse()
}
catch{
    Write-Warning "not a good URL"
}
#not a good URL
```

Answer (score 0):

Add try, catch for handle Exception

```
$url  = "ftpp://google.com/" #Wrong URL Example
try {
$WR = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$WR.Credentials = [Net.NetworkCredential]::new("anonymous","")
$WR.Timeout=3500
$WR.Method = [Net.WebRequestMethods+FTP]::ListDirectory
$WR.GetResponse()
}
catch [System.Net.WebException],[Exception] {
If ($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__) {
    $crap = ($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ ).ToString().Trim();
    Write-Output "Error : $crap";
}
If  ($_.Exception.Message) {
    $crapMessage = ($_.Exception.Message).ToString().Trim();
    Write-Output "Error : $crapMessage";
}
}
```

The output result :

```
Error : The URI prefix is not recognized.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an issue of the network stack, see [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/28908). It's pretty well documented on the net as being able to increase but going lower than ~21 seconds doesn't make a difference. You could use Test-Connection to ensure it's a good URL first, or maybe some other method.

```
try
{
    $null = Test-Connection $url -Count 1 -ErrorAction stop
    write-host good, continue your code here -ForegroundColor Green
}
catch
{
    Write-Warning "not a good URL"
}
```

Also, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ftpwebrequest.timeout?view=netcore-3.1) states the default value is infinite, that is incorrect. Run this test to confirm

```
$WR = [Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
$WR.Credentials = [Net.NetworkCredential]::new("anonymous","")
$WR.Timeout

100000
```